# Autocomplete travando o banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar, codeigniter-3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP e Jquery com o framework Codeigniter 3. Estou utilizando o Postgre e tenho um banco de dados com mais de 1 milhão de registros cadastrados.

Fiz um autocomplete que busca pelo nome de um produto no banco, só que como ele busca em tempo real no banco de dados começa a travar tudo. Testei usando um array estático e funcionou 100%.

Computacionalmente falando como minha base de dados possui muitos registros, qual seria a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

PS: Estou usando esse plugin do jquery (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Estou usando o Full Text Search, mas não criei nenhum índice para ele. Vou tentar criar para ver se melhora. Vejam meu código:

```html
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.titulo AS value 
FROM sistema.produto p
WHERE to_tsvector(p.titulo) @@ to_tsquery(?)
ORDER BY p.id_categoria 
LIMIT 5", array($termo));
```

Comment: Andre, primeiramente para não mexer em sua aplicação. se usa mysql, consulte sobre particionamento de tabelas. Crie um particionamento sobre esses registros e teste.

Answer (score 3):

## PostgreSql FullText Search

Se não quiser mexer de forma significante no software ou infraestrutura, veja sobre [PostgreSql FullText Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html).

É uma função/recurso do PostgreSql para realizar buscas em alguns campos determinador.

## ElasticSearch

Se puder fazer alterações mais significativas, recomendo utilizar [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/) junto com seu *Type Ahead* - ou *Auto Complete*. Esse sim foi todo feito para esse fim. Com um serviço de busca a parte, vc pode criar todas as buscas que precisar, e tira qualquer carga do seu banco de dados principal.

Comment: Gostei da dica amigo, mas na primeira opção meu banco é o PostgreSQL. Você sabe sem tem alguma alternativa? Abraços!

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Thiago a minha consulta já usava o FullText Search (editei o post veja). Mas vi na documentação que você me passou que dá para criar índices pra aumentar a velocidade. Vou tentar aqui obrigado!

Comment: Me diz se funcionou depois.

Comment: Então Thiago, veja o codigo que estou usando la na atualização. As vezes funciona, mas as vezes começa dar erro. Olhei no log do Postgre e consultas que funcionariam normal do pgAdmin dão erro. Acho que é pq fica chamando essa função toda hora que o usuário digita... não sei :(

Comment: Vc está batando na barreira que todos nos passamos: quando o sistema crescem e os recursos "quebra galho" - como esse FullText Search - começam a falhar. Acredito que escalar sua solução é o melhor caminho. Criar um serviço de search individual, sincronizar os dados, e passar a fazer busca em um serviço dedicado para buscas. Se precisar de um *advisor* para esse projeto, entre em contato e podemos conversar.

Comment: Ok, como entro em contato com você? Uma alternativa que eu pensei seria criar uma tabela so com termos de pesquisa. Como ela seria menor acredito que funcionaria.

Comment: Acesse pronext.com.br entre em contato por lá, e diga que precisa de falar comigo Thiago Lunardi sobre desenvolvimento de software.